# "биточки ваще кайф"

Tags: выражения, сленг, музыка

Someone commented on a song I put on the internet with the Russian phrase `биточки ваще кайф`, which to me looks like she's telling me that at this point in the (may I point out, instrumental) track there's some sort of Russian meat [cutlet/chops/meatballs](https://marinaskitchen.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/dsc00711-copy1.jpg) that finally kicks in.

In this context, what could this phrase possibly mean?

Comment: try the search `"бесплатные биты, бесплатные минуса"`. This is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that this "биточки" here is musical slang word, derived from English "beat" (it can be written in Russian as "бит" - compare "Beatles" and "Битлз" for instance). Here's how a [site](http://sample-create.ru/semply/bity) dedicated to musical samples defines the word бит:

> Биты - это ударные партии задающие ритм вашему треку или композиции. Вы можете скачать уже готовые сэмплы битов или сделать их при помощи драм машины или на виртуальном синтезаторе (VST).

So, the phrase is actually praises the beat(s) of your song: "The beats are cool!".

Comment: The beaties are cool)

Answer (score 2):

**Биточки** is a diminutive of borrowed бит *beat*.
**Ваще** is the slang spelling of *вообще*, here meaning *generally, just*.
**Кайф** is literally the buzz or pleasurable effect you get from any substance, used to describe something *cool* or *lit*.

So basically, that comment is tantamount to:

> "[Your] little beats are just lit / just slap!"

PS: The diminutive here is an endearing feature.

Comment: Ваще хоть и образовано от вообще, но, в отличие от вообще, часто выступает в роли междометия, выражающего разные эмоции. Here ваще is close to wow - surprise+approval+surely~. Биточки все-таки изначально котлеты, так что это игра слов, юмор. Также в музыкальном сленге гитаристов 90-2000х есть слово "мясо", возможно, "биточки", как более поздняя версия, являются наследником "мяса". Мясистые биты, мясистый звук. http://guitar.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=54933#:~:text=А%20мясо%20-%20это%20просто,%22мяса%22%20можно%20крутить%20как%20хочется

Comment: Мясо - плотное слаженное звучание, сыгранность коллектива, гармоничное звучание тембров инструментов. "Мясо есть сыгранность гитары, баса и драмсов(drums). эдакое биение... см.метальное(metal music style) мясо, джазовое мясо..."

Comment: Very interesting. *Just* also has the effect of WOW! in this context. In fact, by using *just* here, I could theoretically eliminate the exclamation mark.